# Is there a way to find First execution of cron in the day

Tags: shell-script, cron

Let me explain the exact scenario here:

I have multiple servers ~12 and each server is having a cron entry with execution times vary per Server. For Example

```
Server1:
30 0,8,16 /p1/scripts/forkChild.sh

Server2:
0 2,4,6,18,22 /p1/scripts/forkChild.sh

Server3:
30 6,18 /p1/scripts/forkChild.sh
```

and so on.

What I want to achieve is to while `forkChild.sh` gets executed; I want to know if the current execution is first occurence of run for that day.
Say its 17th Jan, For Server 1, First execution would be 00:30 hrs and similarly for Server3, It would be 6:30.

Even though currently I am achieving this by adding a variable in the script and putting the first occurence of run manually.

Example Server1's `forkChild.sh` :

```
firstExecution=00:30
currenttime=$(date +%H:%M:S)
if [[ "$currenttime" = $firstExecution ]]; then
....
```

Above code is working all good, but sometimes it's not easy to maintain the sync. Is there a solution or cleaner approach someone can suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not just check the time when the cronjobs are set to run on each server? That would be the first instance.

Comment: Use a flag file. Read `man touch stat date`. If the flag file's last modified date is yesterday, this is the first. Modify the flag file when you've finished the "first run" stuff. If the flag file's date isn't  yesterday, modify the flag file.